# CSS-animation in angular not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, sass

I'm trying to toggle a fade-in animation when a button is clicked, and what happens is that the previously hidden element is shown, but there is no animation.

When I try and toggle opacity on/off inside the Chrome developer console, the animation works fine, but not when the event is triggered by a button.

I tried to replicate the code examples provided on the [ngShow documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), by adding this to my CSS:

```
.loader.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.loader.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Of course, with no luck. I also tried adding visibility: visible along with opacity: 1 and other way around for opacity: 0, as seen in my code samples below.

I stripped down the code samples to only contain the parts that I believe are relevant. Please let me know if it's not sufficient enough, and I'll happily provide more.

Thanks in advance.

**SCSS:**

```
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: $dotSize;
    height: $height;

    transition: all linear 1s;
    opacity: 0;

    &.visible {
        transition: all linear 1s;
        opacity: 1;
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loader" ng-class="{'visible': loading}" ng-show="loading">
    Content to be animated
</div>
<button class="button" id="snap" ng-click="snap()">
    Click me
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('controllers', []);

    app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.snap = function() {
            $scope.loading = true;
        };
    }]);
})();
```